# Issue with project explorer in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Hi I am using pycharm for python development. While opening my python project in pycharm, it is opening like below image where name of my project is election, and before that the tabs that have appeared are all parent directories. But I don't want to view like this, I want all the folders and files of the my project election, to appear as tree view in left pane. I cannot figure out how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

File -> Settings -> Project: 'project_name' -> Project Structure -> '+ Add Content Root'

There you can set root directory of project and you will see tree structure of your project.

Answer (score 3):

Try this method:
1) Close all tabs.
2) Click `Windows` on the menu bar, then click `Restore Default Layout`

If this doesnt work, or if it shows you a blank space, press `Alt - 1` to open Project View.

Comment: No it is not working, I want whole directory structure of my project dispalyed as a treeview and nothing on the above tab.

Comment: @Joy I don't get it. Can you post a picture of it?

Comment: Those aren't tabs, those are breadcrumbs. It is called the "navigation bar". You can turn it off in View -> Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm -> Preferences -> Search "Project" -> Project Structure -> Add Content Root